# How to show inner html in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tender").on("change",function(){
            var data = $("#tender").val();
            $.ajax({
                url     : "tender.php",
                data    : {type: data,total: <?php echo $realfinaltotalprice ?>},
                type    : 'post', 
                success : function(result){
                    $("#tenderHint").val(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to get the result in inner html. I tried with  `$("#tenderHint").val(result);` to  `$("#tenderHint").innerHTML(result);` but it is not working. How can I make inner html work on this AJAX code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`html` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) Just change

```
$("#tenderHint").val(result);
```

to

```
$("#tenderHint").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can show the inner html by setting html to the targets like below.

```
$("#tenderHint").html(result);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.